# Linq Join with GroupBy and Sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, left-join

I have a table of transactions and a table of customers as follows:

```
public class Customer
{    
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
 }

public class SalesTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to get a list of the transactions total Amount by each customer and present it with the name of the customer and total transaction amount in a list

I have tried the following linq method syntax

```
await _context.SalesTransactions
            .GroupBy(w=>w.CustomerId)
            .OrderByDescending(g=>g.Sum(t=>t.Amount))
            .ToListAsync();
```

but when I try to run it I get the following error

> InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.

I have also tried the following query syntax

```
var TransactionSummary = await (from w in _context.WalletTransactions
                           //join c in _context.Customers 
                            on w.CustomerId equals c.Id
                            group w by w.CustomerId
                            into ct
                            //from c in ct.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                             ID=ct.Key,
                             TransactionAmount=ct.Sum(a=>a.Amount),
                            // ct.Name
                             }).ToListAsync();
```

but the Sum(w.Amount) is showing error saying that "Sum does not exist in the  current context".

I am also not sure of where to place the grouping clause in the query syntax to achieve grouping the
result by the Customer.Id field.

Please note that the lines I have commented out are clauses that I wish to add but not sure where and how to add them he right way

I wish to get the right way to go about this.

Thank you

**SOLUTION FOUND:**
Thanks to the answer from @Asherguru

I just had to modify it a little to achieve the desired outcome

The following worked

```
var transactions= (await _context.SalesTransactions.Include(x => x.Sender).ToListAsync())
            .GroupBy(w => new { w.CustomerId, w.Sender })
            .Select(x => new 
            {
                CustomerID= x.Key.CustomerId,
                 x.Key.Customer,
                Amount = x.Sum(w => w.Amount)
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
await _context.SalesTransactions
        .GroupBy(w => w.CustomerId)
        .Select(x => new SalesTransactions() 
        {
            CustomerId = x.Key,
            Amount = x.Sum(w => w.Amount)
        }).ToListAsync();
```

[image]

[image]

### EDITED 2

```
await _context.SalesTransactions.Include(x => x.Customer).ToListAsync()
    .GroupBy(w => new { w.CustomerId, w.Customer })
    .Select(x => new SalesTransactions() 
    {
        CustomerId = x.Key.CustomerId,
        Customer = x.Key.Customer,
        Amount = x.Sum(w => w.Amount)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

[image]

Can get name from Customer.Name in SalesTransaction class.

Comment: Thank you for this. Very helpful. However, I am still struggling with adding the name field by joining the name field

Comment: You need to set relationship between Customer's ID and SalesTransactions's CustomerID. Then you can use Include(x => x.Customer) and get name from SalesTransaction.Customer.Name

Comment: There is already a relationship. There is CustimerId field in SalesTransactions table

Comment: then, you can use Include(x => x.Customer). You can get name from that already. No need to join name as both CustomerId are linked.

Comment: Please update the answer so I can accept it. Check my post again I have added a section labelled SOLUTION FOUND where I indicated the needed modification to your answer. Thank you very much. I appreciate your efforts